# PHP - How to upload file uri from mobile device to web server?

Tags: php

I'm trying to build an mobile app that is capable to upload images to server. However, there's some problem with my php script, when I upload data URI of a screenshot, it works fine, but when I upload file URI of an image, the image uploaded into web server is broken. Can anyone help me to check what is wrong with the script?

```
<?php
//Generate a folder if it doesn't exist
if (!file_exists('user_images/'))
{
    mkdir('user_images', 0755, true);
}

//Get submitted data by user
if (isset($_POST['CanvasPic'])) {
    $img1 = $_POST['CanvasPic'];
} else {
    $img1 = '';
}

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
} else {
    $name = '';
}

define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'user_images/');

//Remove some useless string before to create image properly
//Decode base64 then generate new name
if ($img1) { 
    $img1 = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img1);
    $img1 = str_replace(' ', '+', $img1);
    $data1 = base64_decode($img1);
    $file1 = UPLOAD_DIR . $name . "_" . uniqid() . '.jpeg';
    $success = file_put_contents($file1, $data1);
}

//Output a URL where is saved.
$locator = $file1;

//Display a text, otherwise if error happened.
print $locator ? $file1 : 'Could not save the file!';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you php $_FILES superglobals array it is better to file or image uploading using php script to mobile device.

base64_decode()- it time consuming process to upload file to server.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
    $uploadFileName = $name."_".uniqid().".jpeg";
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'user_images/');
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['CanvasPic']['tmp_name'],UPLOAD_DIR.$uploadFileName)) {
        echo "Uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "File was not uploaded.";
    }
```